# how to reset timer observable

Tags: angular, timer, rxjs

I have a timer (which triggers observable) - I located it in the service constructor. Lets say it gets data every 10 seconds (the code is copied by hand, not copy-paste, so excuse me for any typos):

```js
@Injectable({
  provideIn: "root",
})
export class myService {
  isGetFullData: boolean;
  subscription: Subscription;
  myDataSubject = new Subject<any>;
  myDataSubjectChanged : Observable<any> = this.myDataSubject.asObservable(); 

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.subscription = timer(0, 10000)
      .pipe(switchMap(() => this.getData()))
      .subscribe();
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(url).
      pipe
      (
        tap(res => 
        {
           this.myDataSubject.next(res); 
        }), 
        catchError(error => throwError(error))
      );
    /* The data depends on the isGetFullData variable. */
  }
}
```

The service is injected to a component that requires its data.
Now- I have a different component that may change the **isGetFullData** variable.
when this variable changes value, I wan't the **getData()** to be executed immediately, and a result -  the timer starts his cycles again, starting that point.

This is the component that changes the **isGetFullData** value of the service:

```js
export class myComponent {
  constructor(private mySrv: myService) {}

  ToggleGetDataStatus() {
    this.mySrv.isGetFullData = !this.mySrv.isGetFullData;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not using the timer emitted values, so what do you mean by `the timer starts his cycles again`

Comment: @RafiHenig - I'm using it, I've added it to the code - I'm setting the myDataSubject and listen to the myDataSubjectChanged  observable in the relevant component.

Comment: Yes but you aren't using the numeric values, so why reset the timer

Comment: @RafiHenig - I thought of making the first request as "0 time" and then every 10 seconds although  - I tend to concede it - execute the api call immediately and let the timer continue. This might causing an API call and 1 or 2 or 3, etc. seconds afterwards another  call triggered by the timer.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following modifications:

```js
  private readonly getFullDataChanged = new Subject<void>();
  public toggleFullData = () => this.getFullDataChanged.next()

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.getFullDataChanged 
      .pipe(
        startWith(null),
        switchMapTo(timer(0, 10000)),
        mergeMap(this.getData)
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

In your component:

```js
ToggleGetDataStatus() {
  this.mySrv.toggleFullData()
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to make a BehaviorSubject and not just a Subject as trigger?

Comment: @Jonathan Stellwag  I use `BehaviorSubjext` so I can immediately get the first value

Comment: You could also go with startWith.

Answer (score -1):

Found out how to do it - I need to "restart" the timer, by unsubscribe the timer subscription and then set it again. In the service:

```
restartTimer()
{
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  this.subscription = timer(0, 10000)
  .pipe(switchMap(() => this.getData()))
  .subscribe();
}
```

and when the isGetFullData changes (we can use an observable on its subject), execute the restartTimer

Comment: I do not recommend you to subscribe/unsubscribe to reset values or do other operations in rxjs. A subscription should be open as long as you need informations from the observable. Try to check the above answer.